# Used raspi-config for i2c option

Tags: i2c, raspi-config, config.txt

I used: `sudo raspi-config` to select the I2C option but it got into the config.txt file appended to the previous line. I since fixed that, but want to know what I did wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Can you duplicate the bug?  i.e. from a known /boot/config.txt can you run raspi-config and get the same result?  If so it is certainly worth reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what [the current version of raspi-config](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rc_gui/blob/master/raspi-config) does (it's in the `do_i2c()`) function:

```
sed $CONFIG -i -r -e "s/^((device_tree_param|dtparam)=([^,]*,)*i2c(_arm)?)(=[^,]*)?/\1=$SETTING/"
if ! grep -q -E "^(device_tree_param|dtparam)=([^,]*,)*i2c(_arm)?=[^,]*" $CONFIG; then
  printf "dtparam=i2c_arm=$SETTING\n" >> $CONFIG
fi
```

The `sed` command will change the line if it begins with `device_tree_param` or `dtparam` then `=` then something ending with `i2c=` or `i2c_arm=`.

The `grep` line then checks for the same thing and if it's not there, adds it.  Don't ask me why this isn't an if/else; efficiency is not a real concern here anyway.

So note that *won't* change or count a line that's been commented out.